# Joining two tables and using alias for only 1

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to join 2 tables A and B that look like this:

| ID | Time | ID_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10:00 | 5 |
| 2 | 11:00 | 6 |
| 3 | 12:00 | null |

| ID_A | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 13:00 |
| 6 | 14:00 |

Now i join them with

```
select * from A
left join B on ID_A
```

What i need now is a way to make the name of **Time** refer to **A.Time** and **B.Time** refer to **B.Time**.

eg. `select Time from ...` should return A.Time and `select B.Time from ....` should return B.Time or null

Comment: Who or what will refer to those names? Your 'eg.' suggests the query you showed might actually be a subquery for something larger, or maybe the query for a view? Either way the table aliases used in a subquery aren't available outside it, but you can alias the columns with unique names instead. I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 2):

List all the columns and give the conflicting ones aliases using `AS`:

```sql
select a.id,
       a.time,
       a.id_a,
       b.id_a AS b_id_a,
       b.time AS b_time
from   A
       left join B
       on a.ID_A = b.id_a
```

or you can select all of the columns from one table using `<table_identitifier>.*`:

```sql
select a.*,
       b.id_a AS b_id_a,
       b.time AS b_time
from   A
       left join B
       on a.ID_A = b.id_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution could be to rename column in B with a subquery, see the following code as an example:

```
SELECT 
   ID,  
   Time,
   ID_A,
   Time_B
FROM A
LEFT JOIN 
(select ID_A, Time as Time_B from B) b_alias
b_alias on ID_A
```

Comment: that certainly helps. The actual tables have much more columns that are in conflict, so it is a bit cumbersome, but it should work!

Comment: You don't need a subquery to do that, just alias it in the select list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an alias in each table to can use the "select B.Time...". By now you are just calling one A and B but they are not refered as it.